# Finding role by name when it has a space

Tags: node.js, discord.js

My bot can issue roles by mention, but I want it to be given by name (so that there's no need to ping the entire role. This is the syntax of the command: `!role <@user> <role name>`

I'm using discord.js@v12

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {

  if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('706754890294099990')) return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, roles can only be assigned by admins`).then(msg => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      msg.delete()
    }, 5000);
  })

  let rMember = message.mentions.members.first()
  if (!rMember) return message.reply(`You didn't mention any user`).then(msg => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      msg.delete()
    }, 5000);
  })

  let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name. == args[1]) || message.mentions.roles.first()

  if (!role) return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, You haven't written any role name`).then(msg => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      msg.delete()
    }, 5000);
  })

  if (rMember.roles.cache.has(role.id)) return message.reply(`This member already has this role!`).then(msg => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      msg.delete()
    }, 5000);
  })

  if (rMember.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {

  } else {
    await (rMember.roles.add(role.id));
    message.channel.send(`${message.author} Added __${role.name}__ to ${rMember}`);
  }

}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "role"
}
```

Comment: Bot can give role without space, example: !role @ user Moderator
but if i write: !role @ user Dead Inside ,return message (!role)

Comment: If `args` is `msg.content.split(" ")`, then the role will be split between two arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your role has spaces in its name that means that your `args` will be something like this: `['@user', 'Name', 'in', 'parts']`
To get the full name you need to join together all the arguments except for the first one, which is the user. To do that, you can use [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join); here's an example:

```js
let roleName = args
  .slice(1) // Take every element from index 1 to the end
  .join(' ') // Join them back with spaces

let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == roleName) || message.mentions.roles.first()
```

Comment: @Dima Happy to hear that :) You can now mark your question as answered by clicking the tick on the left of this answer: this way everybody will know that your problem is solved and the question will be "closed"

Comment: check my another question, if you understand 'voiceStateUpdate'.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926688/i-want-a-coin-system-for-seating-in-a-voice-channel-per-1-minute